# It's really hard to find the other Stack Exchange sites from Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, network-sites

Friendly *marketing* and *user experience* advice: There are no links or pointers to the rest of the Stack Exchange network from the Stack Overflow site.  Whilst you can do an Internet search for them, this takes you to a search engine, allowing you to see other sites as well, not just the Stack Exchange you are looking for.

I was specifically looking for a Unix Stack Exchange site and had search the Internet for it to find it, even after trawling the Stack Overflow site a lot.

Comment: *"There are no links or pointers to the rest of the Stack Exchange network from the Stack Overflow site."* - There are at least 2: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAhjE.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHXP6.png)

Comment: Also, why should Stack Overflow link to Cooking Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Cerbrus Cookies - because cookies are always important for both programming and as a treat.

Comment: Improving this might reduce off-topic questions, though I'm not sure exactly what the best way to do it would be...I don't really have any concrete suggestions.

Comment: @Catija don't forget roasting! We do great tag BBQ periodically.

Comment: I suppose adding a "network sites" link to the left sidebar might help - it is severely underutilized.

Comment: There are a bunch of links down in the footer under the Stack Exchange Network heading. For the Unix Exchange site that you're looking for, I suggest looking under the Technology link.

Comment: @RobH beat me to the "footer" answer by 18 seconds, but I would add that your post could be improved by sharing *your* experience trying to (unsuccessfully) find links to other SE sites, rather than making the blanket statement that, *"There are no links ..."*.  I think it's a valid point that it could be easier, especially when the footer is a *fairly long* scroll on the main page.  It is *not*, however, correct to say that the links just don't exist.

Comment: To me this remains a global site design problem. The footer is pretty standard, if you don't look there that is a you-problem, not a Stack Overflow problem. But still... "STACK EXCHANGE NETWORK" does not exactly scream at you "Yow, here are other sites where you can ask different types of questions!". It's so ambiguous.

Comment: From a usability point of view, the OP is correct. For instance, [users don't scroll](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-attention/). Even [hallway usability testing](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) would very quickly reveal the problem. It doesn't have to be very sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there is a section in the footer of each Stack Exchange site (including Stack Overflow) with a categorization of other sites.  Selecting a category will take you to a list of the sites:

[image: Stack Overflow Footer]

That said, in the question body, you say:

> There are no links or pointers to the rest of the Stack Exchange network from the Stack Overflow site.

Your question title is more accurate -- I can agree that it is *not* necessarily "easy" to find.  The footer is a long scroll through 50?-something questions on the default SO page.  Having this more discoverable, as @RyanM mention in the comments, could potentially reduce off-topic questions.

Comment: Maybe a feature request to move those links over to the left sidebar would be in order if someone really wants that to happen.